# Convert Keith Hill's PowerShell Get-Clipboard and Set-Clipboard to a PSM1 script

Tags: c#, powershell, multithreading, sta

I'd like to convert Keith Hill's C# implementation of Get-Clipboard and Set-Clipboard into pure PowerShell as a .PSM1 file.

Is there a way to spin up an STA thread in PowerShell as he does in his Cmdlet when working with the clipboard?

[The Blog Post](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!193.entry?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=136851024)
[The Code](http://home.comcast.net/~rkeithhill/MSH/Clipboard.cs)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TextBox doesn't require -STA switch.

```
function Get-ClipBoard {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $tb = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $tb.Multiline = $true
    $tb.Paste()
    $tb.Text
}


function Set-ClipBoard() {
    Param(
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
      [string] $text
    )
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $tb = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $tb.Multiline = $true
    $tb.Text = $text
    $tb.SelectAll()
    $tb.Copy()
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot when I get to work.  Great idea though.

Comment: worked... just had to add one line to your script to make sure System.Windows.Forms was loaded

Comment: Heh, ever escalating techniques. Ok, my next post will be a multi-format clipboard module with no temp files that can handle more than just text.

Answer (score 10):

<sup>See the bottom section for a [cross-edition, cross-platform module](https://github.com/mklement0/ClipboardText) that offers clipboard *text* support in PowerShell Core and in Windows PowerShell v2 - v4.</sup>

An attempt to summarize the state of affairs and options **as of *Windows* PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell *Core* v6.1.0**:

- ***Windows* PowerShell *v5.0+***: Use the ***built-in* [`Get-Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard) and [`Set-Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard)** cmdlets.
- ***Windows* PowerShell *v4.0-*** (v1 - v4.0): has ***no* built-in cmdlets for interacting with the clipboard**, but there are **workarounds**:

  - Use **PowerShell Community Extensions** (PSCX; http://pscx.codeplex.com/), which come with several clipboard-related cmdlets that go beyond just handling text.
  - Pipe to the **standard command-line utility `clip.exe`** (W2K3+ server-side, Vista+ client-side)[1]:

    - Note: Aside from the encoding issues discussed below, **`... | clip.exe` invariably *appends a trailing newline*** to the input; the only way to avoid that is to use a temporary file whose content is provided via *cmd*'s `<` input redirection - see the `Set-ClipboardText` function below.
    - If only ASCII-character (7-bit) support is needed: works by default.
    - If only **OEM-encoding (8-bit) support** (e.g., IBM437 in the US) is needed, run the following first:

      - `$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)`
    - If **full Unicode support** is needed, a **UTF-16 LE encoding *without BOM*** must be used; run the following first:

      - `$OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UnicodeEncoding $false, $false # UTF-16 encoding *without BOM*`
      - Example to test with (the PS console will *display* the Asian chars. as "??", but still handle them correctly - verify clipboard content in Notepad, for instance):

        - `"I enjoyed Thomas Hübl's talk about 中文" | clip # should appear as is on the clipboard`
    - Note: Assigning to `$OutputEncoding` as above works fine in the *global* scope, but not otherwise, such as in a *function*, due to a *bug* as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.0.0-rc.2 - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5763

      - In a non-global context, use `(New-Object ...).psobject.BaseObject` to work around the bug, or - in PSv5+ - use `[...]:new()` instead.
    - Note: `clip.exe` apparently understands 2 formats:

      - the system's current **OEM codepage** (e.g., IBM 437)
      - **UTF-16 LE** ("Unicode")
      - Unfortunately, `clip.exe` always treats a BOM as *data*, hence the need to use a BOM-*less* encoding.
      - Note that the above encodings matter only with respect to correctly detecting *input*; once on the *clipboard*, the input string is available in *all* of the following encodings: UTF-16 LE, "ANSI", and OEM.
  - Use a **PowerShell-based solution with direct use of .NET classes**:

    - Note that clipboard access can only occur from a thread in STA (single-threaded apartment) mode - as opposed to MTA (multi-threaded apartment):

      - v3: *STA is the default* (MTA mode can be entered by invoking `powershell.exe` with the `-mta` switch).
      - v2 and v1: *MTA is the default*; STA mode can be entered by invoking `powershell.exe` with the `-sta` switch.
      - Ergo: Robust functions should be able to access the clipboard from sessions in either mode.
- **PowerShell *Core*** (multi-platform), **as of v6.1.0**,  has ***no* built-in cmdlets for interacting with the clipboard**, not even when run on *Windows*.

  - The workaround is to use platform-specific utilities or APIs - see below.

---

My [`ClipboardText` module](https://github.com/mklement0/ClipboardText) provides
**"polyfill" functions `Get-ClipboardText` and `Set-ClipboardText` for getting and setting *text* from the clipboard**;  they work on **Windows PowerShell v2+** as well as on **PowerShell Core** (with limitations, see below).

In the simplest case (PSv5+ or v3/v4 with the package-management modules installed), you can **install it [from the PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ClipboardText) from an elevated / `sudo` session as follows**:

```
Install-Module ClipboardText
```

For more information, including prerequisites and manual-installation instructions, see [the repo](https://github.com/mklement0/ClipboardText).

- Note: Strictly speaking, the functions aren't *polyfills*, given that their names differ from the built-in cmdlets. However, the name suffix *Text* was chosen so as to make it explicit that these functions handle text only.
- The code gratefully builds on information from various sites, notably @hoge's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573295/45375) and http://techibee.com/powershell/powershell-script-to-copy-powershell-command-output-to-clipboard/1316
- Running on *Windows PowerShell v5+ in STA mode*:

  - The built-in cmdlets (`Get-Clipboard` / `Set-Clipboard`) are called behind the scenes.
    Note that STA mode (a COM threading model) is the default since v3, but you can opt into MTA (multi-threaded mode) with command-line option `-MTA`.
- In all other cases (Windows PowerShell v4- and/or in MTA mode, PowerShell *Core* on all supported platforms):

  - Windows:

    - A P/Invoke-based solution that calls the Windows API is used, via ad-hoc C# code compiled with `Add-Type`.
  - Unix-like platforms: Native utilities are called behind the scenes:

    - macOS: `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`
    - Linux: `xclip`, ***if* available and installed**;
      for instance, on Ubuntu, use `sudo apt-get xclip` to install.
- `Set-ClipboardText` can **accept *any type* of object(s) as input** (which is/are then converted to text the same way they would render in the console), either directly, or from the pipeline.
- Invoke with `-Verbose` to see what technique is used behind the scenes to access the clipboard.

---

<sup>[1] An earlier version of this answer incorrectly claimed that `clip.exe`:

- always appends a line break when copying to the clipboard (it does NOT)

- correctly handles UTF-16 LE BOMs in *files* redirected to stdin via `<` vs. when input is piped via `|` (`clip.exe` *always* copies the BOM to the clipboard, too).</sup>

Answer (score 4):

I just blogged how to do this:

http://www.nivot.org/2009/10/14/PowerShell20GettingAndSettingTextToAndFromTheClipboard.aspx

-Oisin

Comment: This doesn't work with large values for $text. Program 'powershell.exe' failed to execute: The filename or extension is too long

Comment: ouch. well I guess stick with a binary cmdlet, or by starting powershell.exe itself with the -STA flag and using the clipboard methods directly (or use ISE which is in STA mode by default)

Comment: alternatively, you could modify my functions to read/write from a temporary file.

Comment: I just updated my blog post to use a temp file - this avoids your problem. No limit now for text size.

Comment: Rather than invoking [windows.forms.clipboard]::SetText() in a child powershell process, it is probably more efficient to use clip.exe.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your host first.  ISE already runs STA so there is no need to spin up another thread or shell out (which is an optimization that's on my todo list for PSCX).  For the console prompt, which is MTA, then I would shell out to binary code either as Oisin shows or use a simple little C# app like:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class OutClipboard {
  [STAThread]
  static void Main() {
    Clipboard.SetText(Console.In.ReadToEnd());
  }
}
```

And for getting the clipboard contents, Vista and later have clip.exe.

I don't think that even 2.0's advanced functions is ready to let folks party with their own .NET threads in a script.

Comment: At that point I might as well just go with the C# cmdlet.  Seems like the best approach given the threading limitations.  Is there a way to start a job on an STA thread?

Comment: Heh, I was just looking through the Jobs docs for that and didn't come across anything that would give you control of that attribute on a job.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Lee Holme's recipe from the PowerShell Cookbook: [Set-Clipboard](http://poshcode.org/2219). You can use at as Set-Clipboard.ps1, or just drop the code inside a PowerShell function ([here's an example](https://benmccormack.kilnhg.com/Code/Public/Group/WindowsPowerShell/File/Common.ps1?rev=37c866399f52#151-217) from my PowerShell profile).

The script will allow you to get the full piped output to the clipboard, e.g.:

```
dir | Set-Clipboard
```

I originally learned of Lee Holme's solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14529996/166258).

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell 5, we now have `Get-Clipboard` and `Set-Clipboard`.

On Windows Server 2012 R2, where we only have PowerShell 4, I was able to use .NET to manipulate the clipboard.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$copied = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetText()

$to_paste = 'Hello World'
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText($to_paste)
```